# loop through columns in dataframe list using lapply and map

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, purrr

I'd like to create a dynamic HTML list based on a list of dataframes `datalist`. My data is a list of dataframes each with two columns (with not necessarily the same name). I always want the first column of each dataframe to be the list element, and the second column the text seen on hover (using `tippy`).

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)



# list of dataframes
datalist <- list(data.frame(A = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3"), B = c("val_1", "val_2", "val_3")),
                 data.frame(X = c("col_4", "col_5", "col_6"), Y = c("val_4", "val_5", "val_6")),
                 data.frame(A = c("col_7", "col_8", "col_9"), B = c("val_7", "val_8", "val_9")))



# named list
names(datalist) <- c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")

ui <-
  # rowPalette(datafile)
  # Should give me this:
  tagList(
    div(h1("Group 1"),
        tags$li(tippy("col_1", "val_1")),
        tags$li(tippy("col_2", "val_2")),
        tags$li(tippy("col_3", "val_3"))),

    div(h1("Group 2"),
        tags$li(tippy("col_4", "val_4")),
        tags$li(tippy("col_5", "val_5")),
        tags$li(tippy("col_6", "val_6"))),

    div(h1("Group 3"),
        tags$li(tippy("col_7", "val_7")),
        tags$li(tippy("col_8", "val_8")),
        tags$li(tippy("col_9", "val_9")))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code above produces a repetitive output, looping over each row in every data frame. I wrote a function that can create a single list element:

```
# Create function for single li
# name will be col_ and hover with be val_
rowBlock <- function(name) {
  tags$li(tippy(name, name))
}
# rowBlock("test", "tooltip") prints test with a tooltip "tooltip"
```

I figured I could possibly use this function to create a second function that will loop over each dataframe in the list and

1) Give it a header taken from `names(datalist)`

2) Use the rowBlock function with `lapply` but this needs TWO arguments: the first column for the text of the list element and the second column is the hover text of the element.

### This doesn't quite work but maybe it's close???

```
rowPallete <- function(data) {
  Map(function(x, y, z)
  div(h5(x),
      tags$ul(rowBlock(y, z))),
  names(data),
  data[[1]][[1]], #I'm not looping through these properly
  data[[1]][[2]]  #I'm not looping through these properly
  )
}
```

Can anyone help me dynamically achieve the desired output using the datalist as the functions input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map2()` from `purrr` to iterate over two equal length items.

In `rowBlock()`, we can use `apply()` to iterate `tippy()` over rows in each dataframe from datalist and then `map()` to iterate `tags$li()` over those tippy outputs.

I had to reshuffle the order of a few items, so here's the full code block.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

# list of dataframes
datalist <- list(data.frame(A = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3"), B = c("val_1", "val_2", "val_3")),
                 data.frame(X = c("col_4", "col_5", "col_6"), Y = c("val_4", "val_5", "val_6")),
                 data.frame(A = c("col_7", "col_8", "col_9"), B = c("val_7", "val_8", "val_9")))

# named list
names(datalist) <- c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")

library(purrr)

rowPallete <- function(data) {
  map2(names(data),
       data,
       ~div(h5(.x),
            tags$ul(rowBlock(.y)))) %>% 
    map(.,
        tagList)
}

rowBlock <- function(name) {
  apply(name,
        1,
        function(x){tippy(paste(x[1]), paste(x[2]))}) %>%
    map(.,
        ~tags$li(.x))
}



ui <-
  tagList(rowPallete(datalist))

server <- function(input, output) {
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here's an image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @EugeneChong ! I copied your code for `rowBlock` and `rowPallete` but each bullet point is showing `col_1, col_2, col_3` with the hover text `val_1, val_2, val_3` rather than what you've shown in your image (a single <ul> per row) Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, you did not, that was my error.  See the revised solution an let me know any questions.